# Duplicating Filemaker Relationships

Tags: database, filemaker

I am attempting to duplicate some records. My first attempt was to manually re-enter the data, however, I have lost some relationships that are necessary to fill a field. I wonder if I should be implementing a different method, to duplicate the records more efficiently, or if I can just add the necessary relationships to fill the desired field.

These two screencaps are the fields in question, thanks for any input!!

[Empty Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h02g.png)

[Full Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49O0a.png)

Comment: This question is very confusing. You need to put more detail and the screenshots do not help much. You are asking about databases, good start is to briefly describe your data structure. Are you duplicating time-sheet entries and you want them to be auto added to an Invoice? Instead of manual entry try to duplicate the record - there is a script step and there is a menu option under "Records" menu

Comment: thank you for the advice! I admit, I jumped in the deep in on this one, and I am grateful for your help despite the lack of info.

Answer (score 0):

The two primary methods for duplicating records in FileMaker are 1) to use the Duplicate Record command, or 2) to export records out to a file and then import them back into the same table.  Which one you use depends on the how many records you need to duplicate and whether the operation will be need to repeated in the future.

And...I would get that relationship fixed. That will surely cause problems.